# NLog from .net to .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I am trying to convert .net 4.6 project to .net core 3.1, and I stumbled using the NLog.

how to route System.Diagnostics.Trace logs through NLog in .NET Core, what it is the configuration that is needed in the json file

Comment: Seems it is called `AddTraceSource`. See also https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073028/ASP-NET-Logging-using-Trace-Listeners-and-How-to-F and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing

Comment: Thank you for the links. I am trying to configure Trace.Writeline to be directed to a file using nlog. I am trying to avoid injecting ILogger on each class I want to write logs

Comment: Maybe setup a global static ILoggerFactory-variable that you entire application can use. Instead of using System.Diagnostics.Trace ?

Comment: I totally agree with you. We do have like multiple 1000 of trace statements and it would be time consuming to replace each one

Comment: Search and replace also works in NetCore applications :)

Comment: Was trying to avoid that but I guess search it is.